# QGIS QSWAT HUR creation

Tags: qgis, gdal, qswat, ssurgo

I am unable to upload my soil file to the swat editor. Every time I attempt to do this I get an error message saying the file could not be uploaded because it "Cannot get GDAL raster band." I have attempted using GSSURGO and STATSGO data as well as a dataset I found online called na_soil. None of them are able to successfully upload. I have also tried converting STATSGO to raster format, but it shows up at 3 lock files with nothing in them when I look at it in file explorer, QGIS, and QSWAT. I do not know what is causing these issues and I do not know how to resolve it. I am a college student and I am doing this for a term project.

Comment: Provide us some images